# When redirecting to external website the url gets appended to the end of the requested url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to redirect the user to a URl but it is redirecting me to an incorrect url.

views.py:

```
def redirect_shortner(request):
    return redirect('www.google.com')
```

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', redirect_shortner, name='redirect_shortner'),
]
```

The code appears correct to me but the user is incorrectly redirected to a url with the current url appended with the specfied url, i.e. the user is redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.google.com` when `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` is the current url.

Comment: Can you try to redirect this? `https://www.google.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one wants to redirect to some other website, one should provide the *absolute* url (See the question [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)) for the page on the other website. `www.google.com` is not an absolute url, namely it is missing the protocol `https://` hence it is considered as a *relative* url from the page the user is currently on and hence resolves to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.google.com`. Instead you want to write the redirect to be absolute as:

```
def redirect_shortner(request):
    return redirect('https://www.google.com/')
```